# Will multiple Thread instances will refer to same memory block of static class or will it create separate memory block for every thread?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading

I am a newbie in .NET and have many confusions regarding the same. If for every request in a dotnet MVC web application a thread is created and inside that thread if we access static variables, then, will the static variables inside all the threads have common memory or will every single thread contain separate static memory variables?

I don't have any code currently.

Comment: All memory is shared within a process. Only special things like `ThreadStaticAttribute` play with that. You typically don't want to use static values at all, but use whatever mechanism your framework offers for associating state with a specific *request*, so that it doesn't matter how many threads or tasks end up handling it.

Comment: Without any code best answer is: it depends

Comment: In general, static variables represent shared state and should be avoided. Consider that you may have many processes in a farm/cluster/pool serving your website and start from there. Don't start trying to share stuff between threads. For that matter, threads are an implementation detail. You should write your code so it doesn't matter where your task is run.

Comment: As a gross simplification: shared unless marked `[ThreadStatic]`. It is *much* more complex than that though - involving app-domains, generic types, etc; but as a general rule: avoid `static` for anything that changes! you're just asking for problems (except maybe some interlocked counters, etc)

Comment: Just FYI - _"for every request in a dotnet MVC web application a thread is created"_ - that is not true, ASP.NET reuses threads =)

Answer (score 0):

Following is a bit of a simplification, but should provide enough context to answer your question.

The memory model for .NET is such that memory is generally shared across threads and can be done so without synchronizing access. Thus, if you have some class `A`, both its instance *and* static members can be accessed across threads. That is, of course, problematic because multiple threads accessing either could result in concurrency issues or corrupt state.

That said, it is possible to prevent this corruption in a few ways

- use `lock` or some other form of mutual exclusion on both static and instance members
- use statics with [ThreadLocal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadlocal-1?view=net-7.0) or [[ThreadStatic]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threadstaticattribute?view=net-7.0)
- and, if state must be shared across threads, copy it so threads are accessing memory that (hopefully) the original thread won't touch

There are pros and cons to these. It is generally better to have no cross-thread dependencies. In the context of ASP.NET this is especially true. Ideally you want your APIs and/or web page renders to be completely independent with other calls and across calls.

If you find yourself needing `static` members (without `ThreadLocal<T>` or `[ThreadStatic]`) stick to making only read accesses (no writes) against these fields. But even then, the lifecycle of the static field matters; for example, if the static is initialized after requests start accessing the fields, you'll have trouble.

Comment: Discussions about "stack" and "heap" memory imparting some behaviour on the variables allocated in each is a backwards argument. It's like saying that if I open my umbrella it will rain. The CLR defines the behaviour of reference types and value types. The stack and the heap are just implementation that support the semantics. Indeed there is no requirement in the specifications that there needs to be a stack at all. It's just an implementation detail.

Comment: Er, ya, you have a point even though pragmatically threads can get to heap memory and not other threads' stacks stack allocations. I'll update without that language because it is misleading. Although, when I wash my car, it does rain!

Comment: I hear you about washing the car!